# Nativewind V4 with expo Router

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router, nativewind

i'm developpong a react native app using Expo router and Nativewind v4.

evrerything was working perfect, but suddenly the Nativewind classes stopped working.

i tried resetting ths cache, uninstalling and installing the node modules but nothing.

is there something wrong.